# Simple multithreaded Server Client Program

Tags: python, multithreading, try-catch, client-server

I have a multithreaded server and client programs for a simple game. Whenever a client force exits the game, I try to catch the exception with a try catch "except BrokenPipeError" and inform the other players.
I also want to end the exited client thread; however, I take input such as this:

```
while True:
            client = serverSocket.accept()
            t = ServerThread(client)
            t.start()
```

I tried to use a threading event with stop() function; however, I believe I can not use a .join statement to exit the thread because of the way I take input. How should I end the force exited client. I know that multiprocessing library has a terminate function but I am also required to use the threading library.  I tried os_exit(1) but I believe this command kills the entire process. What is the standard exit process for programs such as this?

Comment: .join() is the one of the correct way to stop the thread, another one is to stop main thread, which is not the case. Elaborate on your problem. Why do you think that you can't use join?

Comment: Since I have to run my main server program for any potential client requests, I can't use .join(). Or else it will wait for the child thread to complete and then other clients will not be able to connect. The way I accept clients is above.

Comment: I don't know how your ServerThread is working, but my guess there is infinite `while` loop inside `run` method. You might change your `while True` on `while self.is_connected`, add `is_connected` attribute on ServerThread. And set it to `False` on client disconnect so the thread will exit

Comment: That idea helped a lot. But I still do need to somehow join the ending thread to the main thread right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) do nothing else but waits for thread to stop. 
Thread stops when it reaches end of threaded subroutine. For example

```
class ServerThread(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self,client,name):
      super().__init__(self)
      self.client = client
      self.name = name

   def inform(self,msg):
      print("{}: got message {}".format( self.name, msg ))
      self.client[0].send(msg)

   def run(self):
      while True:
         try:
            self.client[0].recv(1024)
         except BrokenPipeError: #client exits
            # do stuff
            break # -> ends loop
      return # -> thread exits, join returns
```

If you want to inform other clients that someone leaves, i would make another monitoring thread

```
class Monitoring(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(self,daemon=True) # daemon means thread stops when main thread do
      self.clients=[]

   def add_client(self,client):
      self.clients.append(client)

   def inform_client_leaves(self,client_leaved):
      for client in self.clients:
         if client.is_alive():
            client.inform("Client '{}' leaves".format(client_leaved.name))

   def run(self):
      while True:
         for thread in list(self.threads):
            if not thread.is_alive(): # client exited
               self.threads.remove(thread)
               self.inform_client_exits(thread)
         time.sleep(1)
```

So the initial code would looks like

```
mon = Monitoring()
mon.start()
while True:
        client = serverSocket.accept()
        t = ServerThread(client,"Client1")
        t.start()
        mon.add_client(t)
```

Comment: I was actually thinking of this too. I have one question though. Since the server thread dedicated to the client who did not leave, it will be in the waiting state with connectionSocket.recv(1024). I want this thread to know immediately when the other thread is terminated(client left). Is a timeout good idea? So I set a timeout to check if the client sent a message and then check if the opponent(other thread) left the game.

Comment: timeout and non-bocking mode is one way, but if you need remote client to know about something you may use socket.send to send him a message without stopping socket.recv, since "inform" method called from another thread, i'll update code to reflect